# Getting undefined when i try to access value outside function;

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used request to get some infromation from API in nodejs. When i try to access these values outside braces it gives undefined.

```
var tab_det;
    request.post({url:'https://ludochallenge.com/index.php/admin/get_table_id', form: {tournament_id:tournament_id}}, function(err,httpResponse,bodyy){ 
        tab_det = bodyy
        console.log('1 : ' + bodyy);
     }); 
     console.log('2 : ' + tab_det);
```

Result

1 : {"table_id":"2","player_turn":1}

2 : undefined

please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) should be a little closer to the question

Comment: when you run `console.log('2 : ' + tab_det);` the response has not been returned from the query yet so is undefined. Its part of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. Please check Luca's linked question

Answer (score 0):

When the thread reaches  `console.log('2 : ' + tab_det)` It's undefined, because value comes from the ajax call:

```
request.post({url:'https://ludochallenge.com/index.php/admin/get_table_id', form: {tournament_id:tournament_id}}, function(err,httpResponse,bodyy){ 
        tab_det = bodyy
        console.log('1 : ' + bodyy);
     });
```

And response from ajax is reached **after** the line `console.log('2 : ' + tab_det)`